# Joint density of uniform distribution and maximum of two uniform distributions.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent with uniform distribution over $(0,1)$ and set $X=\max\{X_1,X_2\}$. What is the joint density of $(X,X_1)$?

For $0<s,t<1$ we have
\begin{align}
F_{X,X_1}(s,t) &= \mathbb P(X\leqslant s,X_1\leqslant t)\\ &= \mathbb P(X_1\leqslant s,X_2\leqslant s, X_1\leqslant t)\\ &= \mathbb P(X_1\leqslant s\wedge t)\mathbb P(X_2\leqslant s)\\
&= (s\wedge t)s\\
&= \begin{cases}
s^2,& s<t\\
st,& s\geqslant t.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then the joint density should be obtained by differentiating:
$$
f_{X,X_1}(s,t) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial s\partial t} F_{X,X_1}(s,t).
$$
But this yields $f_{X,X_1}(s,t) = \mathsf 1_{\{0<t\leqslant s<1\}}(s,t)$ which doesn't integrate to $1$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no density function. Note that $P(X=X_1) = P(X_2 \leq X_1)=\frac 1 2$. Since the set $\{(x,y): x=y\}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ the distribution of $(X,X_1)$ is not absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure and so there is no density joint function for $(X,X_1)$.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the $2$ somehow!

Comment: I'm afraid this is incorrect. Half the mass is indeed in the lower triangular region (as the 2-dim density $\mathsf 1_{0<t \leq s<1}(s,t)$ OP correctly obtained), the other half is spread along the diagonal $X_1=X$. Think about it: the case where $X_1$ is the max has to take on probability $1/2$. That is, the distribution is a mixture of: (1) the uniform 2-dim density in the lower triangle, plus (2) a 1-dim density (Dirac Delta "wall", if you like) $f_{\text{diag}}(s,t) = s \cdot \delta(s−t)$.

Comment: The CDF as stated in the question post is correct, and the mixed 2nd derivative doesn't exist (in the usual, college freshmen sense) along the region split.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Thank you for the correction. Indeed, $(X,X_1)$ has no density. I have edited my answer.